# Ambiguous column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scope in my model

```
scope :created_this_week, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week) }
```

Which correctly returns the amount of vacancies create that week.

Now I need to see how many of those vacancies have a matching (can have multiple matchings per vacancy) with a state of either "applied" or "accepted"

So I tried to do following:

```
Vacancy.created_this_week.includes(:matchings)
.where(matchings: {state: ["accepted", "applied"]})
```

But I get following error

```
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your scope with this, that should take care of the ambiguity.

```
scope :created_this_week, -> { where("vacancies.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week) }
```